# Paint over a zoomable QPixmap in a QLabel

Tags: c++, qt

My purpose is to provide a widget in which I can display an image, click anywhere on this image and display where I clicked. 
To do this I used [Qt's image viewer example](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/widgets-imageviewer.html). I simply added a method to draw on the pixmap when I click :

```
void drawGCP(int x, int y)
{
    // paint on a "clean" pixmap and display it
    // origPixmap is the pixmap with nothing drawn on it
    paintedPixmap = origPixmap.copy();  
    QPainter painter(&paintedPixmap);
    painter.setPen(Qt::red);
    painter.drawLine(x - lineLength, y, x+lineLength, y);
    painter.drawLine(x, y - lineLength, x, y + lineLength);
    label->setPixmap(paintedPixmap);
}
```

It works perfectly fine. The problem comes when I zoom in. The label is resized, and I don't know how, some sort of blur is added to the image.
Which is what I want. But, the cross that I draw is also blurred, and the lines are several screen-pixels wide. I want the cross to be always 1-pixel wide.

I tried to do the same thing with a QGraphicsView and QGraphicsPixmapItem. QGraphicsView has a built-in zoom, but here the blur is not applied.

How can I draw 1-pixel wide lines over a QPixmap displayed by a zoomable QLabel ?

**update:**
Here is how I call drawGCP :

```
void ImageGCPPicker::scaleImage(double factor)
{
    scaleFactor *= factor;
    if (scaleFactor < MIN_ZOOM)
    {
        scaleFactor /= factor;
        return;
    }
    if (scaleFactor > MAX_ZOOM) 
    {
        scaleFactor /= factor;
        return;
    }

    horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(int(factor * horizontalScrollBar()->value() + ((factor - 1) * horizontalScrollBar()->pageStep()/2)));
    verticalScrollBar()->setValue(int(factor * verticalScrollBar()->value() + ((factor - 1) * verticalScrollBar()->pageStep()/2)));

    label->resize(scaleFactor * label->pixmap()->size());
    drawGCP(GCPPos.x(), GCPPos.y());
}
```

As you can see I draw the cross after the scaling is done.

Comment: draw the cross after zoom.

Comment: @UmNyobe Maybe it is that simple. But I don't see how to do it differently from what I do. Can you take a look at my update please ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are painting your cross then zooming, when you should zoom then painting.

```
label->setPixmap(paintedPixmap);
```

will scale `paintedPixmap`, with ***your cross already painted on the pixmap***. You can modify `drawGCP` as follow:

1. create a `paintedPixmap` with the ***label dimension***
2. Adjust the position `int x, int y` using the scale factor
3. Paint the cross on `paintedPixmap` with the new coordinates.

Basically

```
void drawGCP(int x, int y, double factor)
{
    //redundant with factor
    bool resizeneeded = (label->size() != origPixmap(size));
    paintedPixmap = resizeneeded ? origPixmap.scaled(label->size()) : origPixmap.copy() ;  
    QPainter painter(&paintedPixmap);
    painter.setPen(Qt::red);

    //adjust the coordinates (can be done when passing parameters)
    x *= factor;
    y *= factor;
    painter.drawLine(x - lineLength, y, x+lineLength, y);
    painter.drawLine(x, y - lineLength, x, y + lineLength);

    //will not scale pixmap internally
    label->setPixmap(paintedPixmap);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Unfortunatly resizeneeded is always false. I assumed it is label->size() == origPixmap.size();

Comment: @undu I made a mistake. it should be `label->size() != origPixmap(size)`. I obviously didnt run this code so there might be small mistakes like this